# why am i unable to gain access to remote pc through smb while having correct credentials?

Tags: attacks, smb

I have set up my ethical hacking and penetration lab. My host OS is Windows 10 and target 0S is Windows 7. I want to penetrate into Windows 7 from Windows 10 through SMB.

When I try to penetrate, it says access denied. Considering this problem, how should I penetrate?

[image]

Comment: Please do not screenshots of text. Copy/paste it in your question

Comment: And it does not appear as though you are trying to 'penetrate', you are just trying to log in. Do you have a network connection? Is the service running on the target? Does the firewall allow access? It looks like you have some basic OS things to work on. This isn't a security question. Make sure your lab is set up properly and confirm that the connections you expect actually exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your credentials does not have permissions to this PC.
1. If you are using a Domain base network (not a workgroup) you need to check the permission for this user in the Active Directory user list.
2. If you are using a local credentials , check in the local (win 7) user list `This PC->manage->System Tools->Loacl Users...->Users` that you have the current user in the list, if not create it and give it the specific creds that you want.